# How right print result search preg_replace inside fetch_assoc() result mysql?

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$i = $result->fetch_assoc();
preg_replace("/\{(.*?)\}/", $i["$1"], $content);
```

*Error - Undefined variable: $1*

```
// $1 - 'string'; // result search preg_replace()
// $i['string'] = 'hello';
```

How right syntax will be for print 'hello'?

Comment: in php " A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore"

Comment: @Dagon - $1 - it result search preg_replace()

Comment: whats `$1 - 'string';` suppose to mean ?

Comment: $1 is not a valid variable name in PHP.

Comment: $1 - 'string' - it result search. example - https://regex101.com/r/iQ0yF2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok next time please spend a little more time on asking the question:

```
<?php

$i['string'] = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
$content = "test test test  {string} testtesttesttesttest";


$x=preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*?)\}/", function($m) use($i){
  return $i[$m[1]];
},  $content);


echo $x;
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/u29uKh

for this particular approach you need to use preg_replace_callback() requires PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 1):

You can make your replacements faster using `strtr`. To do that, you only need an associative array, but this time, all keys must be enclosed between curly brackets.

```
$i = $result->fetch_assoc();
$keys = array_map(function($k) { return '{' . $k . '}'; }, array_keys($i));
$trans = array_combine($keys, $i);
$content = strtr($content, $trans);
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable name can't start with a number in PHP. It must start with an underscore or letter.

Comment: $1 - it result search preg_replace()